# Is there anyway I can use my Phones GPS in My .Net Application

Tags: .net, gps

I am Planning to build a GPS Application for PC is there any anyway I can use my phone GPS System for the purpose

Comment: That will probably depend on your phone

Comment: I have Nokia 5230, HTC IncredibleS for now, one is Symbian 6 and another Android Phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build an app for your phone to send the location to a remote server, and then get it from your PC app. Similarly you could connect use a webservice to get the phone's location from your PC app (e.g. Google Latitude : http://code.google.com/apis/latitude/)

To get more help, please explain what kind of GPS info you want to use in your app (only the position, or satellites info?...), and what kind of phone you have.

Comment: I have Nokia 5230, HTC IncredibleS for now, one is Symbian 6 and another Android Phone, I need complete information about position and satellites info

Comment: If you just want to follow the phone's location, Latitude works with all those platforms (http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=136640) ; getting satellites info is possible on S60 and Android (a bit less detail) but you would have to code the GPS-reporting applications and server part yourself.